# Cypress - Find an element that contains another element with a certain attribute

Tags: cypress

Title says it all, I can't figure out how can I do something like

Get .card that has button with attribute id=random (the code should return the card and retry the whole process until found, ex: if it finds a card but not a button with that id it should look redo the .carda search)

How I tought it would work but actually doesnt because doesnt retry the .get and if the .find succedes it returns the button

`cy.get(".card").find("button[id=random]")`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add .parent('.card')
`cy.get(".card").find("button[id=random]").parent('.card');`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach:

`cy.get(".card:has('button[id=random]')")`

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's more clear to split selecting and filtering parts into two separate method calls like so

```
cy.get('.card').filter(':has(button[id=random])')
```

Also you can add custom Cypress command in `commands.ts` to improve your developer experience. See more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e).

```
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable<Subject> {
            filterHas(selector: string): Chainable<JQuery>;
        }
    }
}

Cypress.Commands.add(
    'filterHas',
    {prevSubject: 'element'},
    (subject, selector) => cy.wrap(subject).filter(`:has(${selector})`),
);
```

And use it like so

```
cy.get('.card').filterHas('button[id=random]')
```